# Do the exponential in the Split-Step method correspond to the solutions of the split equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider $u_t = (L+M)u$ where $u(x,t)$ is a vector function and $L,M$ are linear operators. The exact solution of this equation is $u(x,h)=e^{(L+M)h}u(x,0)$ where $h$ is the time step size. If we consider the two split equations $$v_t = Lv, \; v_t = Mv$$ then their solutions are $e^{hL}v(x,0)$ and $e^{hM}v(x,0)$ respectively. The idea of split-step method is toapproximate $e^{h(L+M)}$ by a sequence of split operators, e.g, $$u(x,t) \approx e^{\frac{1}{2}hL}e^{hM}e^{hL}\cdots e^{hL}e^{hM}e^{\frac{1}{2}hL}u(x,0)$$

Question:

1. Does the above approximation mean we are supposed to *multiply* the solutions we write for the split equations at the corresponding time steps?

---

Example: Consider the NLS $i\partial_t u = -\partial_{xx}u - |u|^2 u$

The first split equation is $i\partial_t u = - \partial_{xx}u$
whose solution is $$u^{m+1} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[e^{-i |k|^2 h}\mathcal{F}[u^{m}]]$$

Does this solution correspond to one of the exponential terms in the above approximation, say, the ones with $L$? So the the first term $e^{\frac{1}{2}hL}$ is a half time-step of my above solution to the linear split equation? Then, am I supposed to multiply that solution (what does that even mean) by the solution of the nonlinear split equation at a full time step?

Comment: No, you don't multiply the solutions together, it is more a composition of the solutions. In your example, you would solve the nonlinear problem $u_{t} = i \lvert u \rvert^{2} u$ first, then use the solution of the nonlinear problem as the initial condition for the linear problem $u_{t} = -i u_{xx}$, then use the solution of the linear problem as the actual solution at time $h+1$. I gave a detailed response about operator splitting that answers your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3421037/using-lie-trotter-integrators-for-solving-pdes/3421109#3421109).